Area of damage, where an explosion happens and deals damage to all enemies exactly once with Physics2d.OverlapCircleAll(...), but doesnt work
As in the title, I am trying to use overlapcircleall to deal damage to all enemies exactly once, but sometimes works correctly, but sometimes the damage is applied multiple times to the same enemy, where each enemy should have been dealt damage exactly once if they are inside the explosion radius. When testing the game, i believe the higher the amount of enemies inside the explosion area, the bigger the chances of dealing damage multiple times to all enemies inside that area. I have watched some videos and tried to fix it, but nothing seems to work. I also tried using circle collider instead but i get the same problem. But overlapcircleall seems to work better at least than circlecollider.
        int bazucaDamage = GameObject.Find("Bazuca").GetComponent<WeaponScript>().damage;
        circleCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        float explosionRadius = circleCollider.radius;
        int enemyLayer = 1 << 6;
        int playerLayer = 1 << 3;
        Collider2D[] hitCollidersEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, explosionRadius, enemyLayer);
        foreach (Collider2D hitCollider in hitCollidersEnemies)
        {
            // Try to get the Enemy component (or any script that handles taking damage)
            ZombieScript enemy = hitCollider.GetComponent<ZombieScript>();

            if (enemy != null)
            {
                // Apply damage to the enemy
                enemy.TakeDamage(bazucaDamage);
            }
        }

        Collider2D[] hitCollidersPlayer = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, explosionRadius, playerLayer);

        if(hitCollidersPlayer.Length > 0)
        {
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerScript>().TakeDamage(bazucaDamage);
        }

        StartCoroutine(EndExplosion());

The player also takes more damage if the enemies takes more damage than what it actually should.

Are there multiple colliders on your enemies? The Overlap functions hit every collider, not every gameObject
